# Upload image to database using angular

Tags: node.js, angular, post, avatar

I got stuck while uploading updating user avatar on my website. I'm using angular and need to upload image using form  and get base64 encoding of this image to pass as a parameter into my backend.

```
  onUploadFinished(event){
     const avatar ={
       avatar:event.file
     }
     console.log(avatar)

     //validate avatar    
     if(!this.validateService.validateAvatarUpdate(avatar.avatar)){
       this.flashMessage.show('Please, select a new avatar', {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout:3000});      
       return false;
     }


     this.updateService.updateAvatar(avatar).subscribe(data=>{
       console.log()
       if(data/*.success*/){ //commented cause response doesnt have property success but still registering user without displaying the flash message
         this.flashMessage.show('You successfuly changed your avatar', {cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout:3000});
         this.router.navigate(['/profile'])
         this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile=>{
           this.user = profile.user;
         },
         err=>{
           console.log(err);
           return false;
         });
       }else{
         this.flashMessage.show('Something went wrong', {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout:3000});
         this.router.navigate(['/profile'])
       }
     });
   }
```

I was trying to use ng2-image-upload here is html

```
 <h6>Upload new photo...</h6>
      <!-- <form (submit)="onUserAvatarSubmit()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="avatar" class="text-center center-block well well-sm">
        <p></p>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload" type="submit">
      </form> -->
      <image-upload name="avatar" [class]="'customClass'" 
        [headers]="{Authorization: this.authToken}"
        [buttonCaption]="'Choose an Image'" 
        [dropBoxMessage]="'or just drop them here'" 
        (uploadFinished)="onUploadFinished($event)" 
        [url]="''">
      </image-upload>
```

Maybe anyone had such experience with uploading images, so give me some tips how to deal with it. Thanks [here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU85n.png) So you see when displaying this image we can see its base64 but I cant take it.

Comment: Show error log and response from your backend.

Comment: I don't have error. Using this module I just get response with name type and size of image, but I need base 64 and type

Comment: I've uploaded screenshot